# Overflow and position - scrolling doesn't show all webpage

Tags: css, html

I've been learning some things about HTML, CSS and jQuery to make my personal website.

I've hit a wall when I tried adding bigger menus, now when I scroll it doesn't show everything and I can't figure out why.

The best way to explain the problem, especially since I don't know most of the technical vocabulary, is showing it:
http://jsfiddle.net/jcml/kmxdo4ha/

```
   I don't know what part of the code should I paste to avoid pasting everything.
```

So I identify two problems:

1 - It doesn't show the whole menu when scrolling up or down
(while keeping it vertically centered - the menu will change height while navigating)

2 - The menu.ico also scrolls and might get hidden after closing the menu

**Edit:** I figure the reason for problem #1 but then the menu can't be vertically centered. Removing this:

```
.links ul{
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

**Edit2**: the problem with the menu.ico div can be seen if you enter the menu, scroll all the way down and close the menu. The menu button wont show the stripes until you hover it and scroll up.

**Edit3:** I think I found a way to fix problem #2, which involves changing all the website structure. Well it's good practice anyway!

Comment: Why would you want the menu to be vertically centered if it could potentially overflow (meaning the menu can be longer than the viewport)? Your menu should start with the first item... not in the middle; that would be confusing for users.

Comment: Some menus will be short, while other will be long. And if I'm able to make it work, a short menu will become longer after clicking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem number 2.

Basically I had to change the div structure in order that the scrolling in one of them didn't move the other one. This was the reason. I had imagined a different navigation at first that worked with the previous div structure.

As for the problem number 1 it was fixed with the Edit number one in original post, but it presented other problem.
is not easy to explain with the navigation not finished, I'll try to fix it later and if I can't manage to do it I'll share the problem here later.

Anyway, here is the new version that fixed the #2:
http://jsfiddle.net/jcml/bby7522h/

```
I don't know what part of the code should I paste to avoid pasting everything.
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix your first problem you could use flexbox. You would have to replace the style you found out to be the problem to something like this:

```
.links ul{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:center;
    height:100%;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmxdo4ha/1/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It does work better but with smaller windows it will hide part of the menu anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean about the .ico

But I'm sure if you add some `padding-top: 20px;` to menu wrapper and maybe some `padding-bottom: 20px;` your menu shouldn't be cut off.

If you don't have a menu wrapper, simply nest a div around the text menu items in question.

```
.menunavwrapper { 
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px; // sample
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

HTML.

```
<section class="menunavwrapper">
<!-- menu items, list items etc -->

<ul>
<li>sample</li>
</ul>

</section>
```

Comment: Hi, the problem with the menu.ico div can be seen if you enter the menu, scroll all the way down and close the menu. The menu button wont show the stripes until you hover it and scroll up. I tried the wrapper and if I used it correctly it doesn't work.